# ASP.NET: Redirects loop with custom SEO redirect HttpModule

Tags: asp.net, redirect, http-status-code-301, infinite-loop, httpmodule

I wrote my httpModule attached on BeginRequest to handle SEO URL transforms and 301 redirects. Most of the things could be done with URL Rewrite, but I wanted a more flexible option and also URL Rewrite would issue multiple redirects for each transformation (adding "www" is a redirect, switching to lowercase URL is another one, adding a trailing "/" another one and so on...) whilst my httpModule checks all the conditions (including http/https if the page has to be secure or not), transforms the URL and then performs a single 301 redirect.

The issue I'm facing is this... it seems that IIS 7.5 upon a request to http://www.example.com/mydir/ transforms this internally in http://www.example.com/mydir/default.aspx and this triggers an endless loop with my module which attempts to remove the "default.aspx" part and permanently redirect to http://www.example.com/mydir/

What happens on BeginRequest in my module is quite simple. For each request I call a function CheckRedirects() which checks for all the rules and sends back a null string if no redirection is needed or the sanitized url if there is a redirection to perform.

I don't know which default module does this "internal" redirection, which actually is not a real redirect since if you check what happens on the network when you go to http://www.example.com/mydir/ there is no redirection to http://www.example.com/mydir/default.aspx, so is just a sort of "internal" redirection, nonetheless it mess up my module creating an infinite loop

I access the current request URL with

```
Dim request As HttpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request
Dim url As System.Uri = request.Url
```

EDIT: as a side note, if I do the same redirect using URL Rewrite 2.0 module, no infinite loop is triggered. This makes me think that the URL Rewrite 2.0 module is up in the IIS module chain, before the internal "default.aspx" module is execute.
The rule for URL Rewrite is:

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Default Document" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)default.aspx" />
          <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

The problem is that if I mix URL Rewrite and my custom HttpModule I will end up having multiple redirects the same... just consider a simple scenario http://example.com/defaultp.aspx
This will end up with 2 redirects, one from the URL Rewrite module which will remove the "default.aspx" and then another one from my custom HttpModule that will add the "www."